# how to modify boostrap input length

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

> Hi, I have a rudimentary question. How can I specify the length of
>   bootstrap input?
>
> In the code below, the input length is too large, and I want to make
>   it a little bit shorter.
>
> Is there any bootstrap class for it?  its seems when we add number "2"
>   in front of "form-control", like form-control2, make it shorter, but it is too short.
>
> I also tried to change "size" attribute of the input and it didn't work
>   either.
>
> thank you for your help.

```js
import React from "react";

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div className=" container input-group ">
      <div className="input-group-prepend ">
        <button className="btn btn-danger" type="button">
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control "
        placeholder="what are you looking for ?"
        aria-label=""
        aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class in css, in my case it's **length60px** that specifies the width of the input field, be sure to use !important. Use both form-control and the new class on the className/class attribute of the input field.

See code below;

```css
.form-control{
  max-width:100%;
}

.length60px{
  width:60px !important;
  /*you could also use any number with %; 50%, 100%, etc*/
}
```

```html
<input class='form-control length60px' />
```